# "classes" parallel in TestNG test suite doesn't work when executing the suite in TestNG Ant task

Tags: automated-tests, testng, selenium-grid

I set up Selenium grid2 and it works well with following paralleled TestNG test suite:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Sample Test Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test in Chrome" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testCases.SampleCase1" />
            <class name="testCases.SampleCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

But the parallel doesn't work any more when I execute the tests in TestNG Ant task.

And it works again after I change the parallel mode in the test suite file with "tests" as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Sample Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test1 in Chrome" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testCases.SampleCase1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2 in Chrome" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testCases.SampleCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So does that mean TestNG ant task doesn't support "classes" paralleled test suite?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved after replace the tsetng.jar from version 6.2 to 6.8.